# show minimum cycles on a undirected graph using Floyd-Warshall

Tags: c++, c, graph, floyd-warshall, floyd-cycle-finding

I'm having some problems with this.
First, i used Floyd-warshall to show all min cycles on a directed graph and it worked, but then I tried using it with undirected graph and it doesn't work like I need.

For example, lets say I have this graph:

```
INF     INF     19      14      8
INF     INF     13      INF     9
19      13      INF     INF     3
14      INF     INF     INF     10
8       9       3       10      INF
```

This should look something like this:

[image: Graph representation]

Anyway, since you can represent a undirected graph as a directed graph (just like i did in the example matrix), Floyd Warshall should work, but the results aren't what I expected. Using the same graph example, this is the matrix with the min path cost:

Min path cost:

```
16      17      11      14      8
17      18      12      19      9
11      12      6       13      3
14      19      13      20      10
8       9       3       10      6
```

And this is the matrix with the path:

```
 (0 4 0) (0 4 1) (0 4 2) (0 3)   (0 4)
 (1 4 0) (1 4 1) (1 4 2) (1 4 3) (1 4)
 (2 4 0) (2 4 1) (2 4 2) (2 4 3) (2 4)
 (3 0)   (3 4 1) (3 4 2) (3 4 3) (3 4)
 (4 0)   (4 1)   (4 2)   (4 3)   (4 2 4)
```

Since im interested just in cycles, I only need the matrix's diagonal here.

Anyway, lets take 0 - > 0: the result is (0 4 0) which cost is 16

Anyway, since Im looking for min cycles I expected something like:

0 -> 0, Path (0 4 2 0) (or 0 2 4 0 since is a undirected graph, but I just need one of them) and cost 30.

This is the floyd-warshall code in fact:

```
for (k = 0; k < V; k++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < V; j++)
        {
            if (dist[i][k] != INF && dist[k][j] != INF &&
                dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j]) {

                dist[j][i] = dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];
                path[i][j] = path[j][i] = path[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know what I need to change to get the right result (or maybe that is the right result and I think isn't).

Comment: Since you're working on an un-directed graph, the path 0 -> 4 -> 0 is perfectly valid.